# python extract capitalized words using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract the word which is capital and occurs 3 or 4 before word "cell" or "cells"

example 
:

> Briefly, MCF-7 idential cells grown as described above were treated with a range of LTX-diol or iso-LTX-diol.

I would like to extract MCF-7 from above example.

I tried to use `[A-Z0-9-]+cells`, but its returning cells, instead of MCF-7

Comment: `MCF-7` occurs _two_ words before the words `cells`.  Please clarify your matching rules.

Comment: `occurs 3 or 4 before word "cell" or "cells"` 3 or 4 letters/spaces/particular letter ?

Comment: Try `[A-Z]\S*(?=(?:\s+\S+){2,3}\s+cells?)`

Comment: Also, what is the logic by which only certain words should match?  For example, why is `Briefly` not also a match here?

Comment: I am looking for a cell name and my assumption is that there would be a word "cell" and the actual cell name would be 1- 4 words before the cells with captial letter. Briefly would be ignored later as its english word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that you want to match a word beginning with a capital letter, which in turn is followed by 1 to 4 other words, followed then by `cell` or `cells`.  We can try matching using the following pattern:

```
([A-Z][^ ]*)(?=\s+(?:[^A-Z]\S*\s+){1,4}cells?)
```

The positive lookahead at the end of the pattern asserts the requirement for 1 to 4 words occurring before `cell` or `cells`.

```
input = "Briefly, MCF-7 idential cells grown as described above were treated with a range of LTX-diol or iso-LTX-diol."

r1 = re.findall(r"([A-Z][^ ]*)(?=\s+(?:[^A-Z]\S*\s+){1,4}cells?)", input)
print(r1)

['MCF-7']
```